# Electronic medical devices through British airport security

Tags: uk, airport-security

I heard that British airport security had a policy of disposing of electronic equipment if you were unable to prove that you can turn them on. Is this true? What if I am carrying a spare insulin  pump or a similar medical related device which could not be turned on at will?

Comment: That's why you should check in electronics that require an electrical outlet, even though there may be inseat power in the flight.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi and have it promptly stolen? Airlines explicitly warn against checking anything valuable.

Comment: @jwenting Have you tried [shipping them](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34461/shipping-luggage-vs-checking-it-for-us-domestic-air-travel/34487?noredirect=1)?

Comment: @jwenting The problem with shipping is the risk. And also the fact that this device should be available when needed. Abroad post offices are also not as consistent with the UK.

Answer (score 4):

OK So I went to the airport. I was carrying the official documentation for my device signed by the manufactures and doctors. I was allowed to not put my device in the xray (in case of damage). The device was swabbed and they did not require my to turn it on. The documentation given by the manufactures explained why this was so and contact details etc. The security staff said it was fine and I proceeded with my travel. This was exiting the UK.